# DriveDX Won't Load On MacPro5,1 Internal SSD on PCI Card

Tags: ssd

DriveDX Won't Load On MacPro5,1 Internal SSD on PCI Card
I have a license.
Dialog box says won't load because not allowed to run DriveDX from an external drive. OSX does flag my internal SSD on PCI card as an external drive but it is internal. 2 weeks and NO Response from developer BinaryFruit. Infuriating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: I posted because binary fruit has not responded at all since I requested their help via their online support over 2 weeks ago. I have requested same help from them at least 3 times over the past 2 weeks. They have not provided support, therefore I have turned to this site for the support that BinaryFruit has not supplied.

Comment: Just for grins 3 days ago I tried again to install DriveDX on my SSD. Surprise to me it recognized my license and loaded. I had not received any communications from BinaryFruit nor had I made any system changes since my last attempt to install. I emailed BF for the 4th time, this time informing them DriveDX had installed. Maybe BF changed something, maybe magic occurred. Whatever, BF remained consistent and didn't communicate with me.  Sigh. Guess this issue should be closed on this board. Thanks for allowing me to post.